# How can I get a named tuple instance from its name in python?

Tags: python, instance, namedtuple

I have a set of named tuple instances. E.g.:

```
   CostFN = namedtuple('CostFN', ['name', 'func', 'args'])
   tuple_lin_1 = CostFN(name="lin_1", args=args_for_1, func1=func_1)
   tuple_lin_2 = CostFN(name="lin_2", args=args_for_1, func1=func_2)
   tuple_lin_3 = CostFN(name="lin_3", args=args_for_2, func1=func_1)
   tuple_lin_4 = CostFN(name="lin_4", args=args_for_2, func1=func_2)
```

I am saving the instance name, and I want to access the relevant instance from its name.
Something like:
`my_tuple = CostFN.get("lin4")`
How do I achieve that?

Comment: You have to build a `dict` yourself. `CostFN` itself doesn't know about its own instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in any reasonable way. Objects don't *have* names in the way you think they do, names are *bound* to objects. So `tuple_lin_4` is a name that contains a binding to the associated instance of `CostFN`, but the instance has *no* idea it's bound to that name. Similarly, the instance knows it is of type `CostFN`, but `CostFN` doesn't know about its own instances. So you've got two layers where the linkages don't work the way you intend.

If looking up instances by name is an issue, I'd suggest making a `dict` mapping names to instances, rather than using individual named variables. If you really wanted to, you could do terrible things with a custom `__new__` to cache instances by name on a `dict` tied to the class, but frankly, even that's going too far; you likely have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) if you think you need a behavior like this at all.

Comment: To be clear: There are *un*reasonable ways to do this with [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) and the like. They're wildly inefficient for the purpose, and if you *think* you need them for anything other than weird debugging scenarios (`gc.get_referrers`'s own docs say "Avoid using `get_referrers()` for any purpose other than debugging."), you're *wrong*; you've got [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), and need to reconsider your Y.